# A problem with passing an array from activity to a fragment

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I get a very weird error, even though the code looks fine(to my mind).
I get this error

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1`

I am saving data from multiple `EditText`-s in my fragment then put them in an `array` and send in parent activities which then send it in my database. Then after I press a `button` to show me the fragment with the text from the `array` the app crashes.
Here is my code:

**Others.java**

```
public class Others extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyAsyncTask1 mt;
    private String numberPickersValues;
    private Button button;
    private NumberPicker numberPicker1;
    private NumberPicker numberPicker2;

    public static String EXTRA_DATA="com.example.schedule.example.EXTRA_DATA";
    /*public static List EXTRA_DATA_arr2= Collections.singletonList("com.example.schedule.example.EXTRA_DATA_arr2");
    public static List EXTRA_DATA_arr3= Collections.singletonList("com.example.schedule.example.EXTRA_DATA_arr3");
    public static List EXTRA_DATA_arr4= Collections.singletonList("com.example.schedule.example.EXTRA_DATA_arr4");
    public static List EXTRA_DATA_arr5= Collections.singletonList("com.example.schedule.example.EXTRA_DATA_arr5");*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_others);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        numberPicker1=findViewById(R.id.numberpicker1);
        numberPicker2=findViewById(R.id.numberpicker2);
        numberPicker1.setDescendantFocusability(numberPicker1.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        numberPicker2.setDescendantFocusability(numberPicker2.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        numberPicker1.setMinValue(7);
        numberPicker1.setMaxValue(11);
        String[] set_values_for_NP2=new String[]{"А","Б","В","Г","Д"};
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(0);
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(set_values_for_NP2.length-1);
        numberPicker2.setDisplayedValues(set_values_for_NP2);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.Others);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int n1=numberPicker2.getValue();
                numberPickersValues=""+numberPicker1.getValue()+numberPicker2.getDisplayedValues()[n1];
                mt=new MyAsyncTask1();
                mt.execute(numberPickersValues);

            }


        });
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.Search:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                ,Search.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                ,MainActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.Others:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void openOthers2() {
        int n1=numberPicker2.getValue();
        String numberPickersValues=""+numberPicker1.getValue()+numberPicker2.getDisplayedValues()[n1];
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Others2.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA,numberPickersValues);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    class MyAsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Database db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
            if(db.classDao().doesGroupExist(params[0])){
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Others2.class);
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA,numberPickersValues);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArray("array_for_m", db.classDao().findFromMonday(numberPickersValues));
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                openOthers2();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**Others2.java**

```
public class Others2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private Mon2Fragment mon2Fragment;

    MyAsyncTaskOthers2 mt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_others2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mt = new MyAsyncTaskOthers2();
                mt.execute();

            }
        });
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Others.class));
            }
        });
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        adapter.AddFragment(new Mon2Fragment(), "Mon");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tue2Fragment(), "Tue");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Wed2Fragment(), "Wed");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Thu2Fragment(), "Thu");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Fri2Fragment(), "Fri");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public String sendData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        return intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA);
    }

    public String[] sendDataM() {
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] array=b.getStringArray("array_for_m");
        return array;
        /*Intent intent = getIntent();
        return intent.getStringArrayExtra("my_stringm");*/
    }

    class MyAsyncTaskOthers2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Database db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
            Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
            Mon2Fragment mon2Fragment = (Mon2Fragment) page;
            if (!db.classDao().doesGroupExist(intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA))) {
                ClassEntity new_group = new ClassEntity();
                new_group.id_of_a_group = intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA);
                new_group.monday = mon2Fragment.Text_getter();
                db.classDao().insert(new_group);
            }
          else{
                db.classDao().update(mon2Fragment.Text_getter(), intent.getStringExtra(Others.EXTRA_DATA));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**Mon2Fragment.java**

```
public class Mon2Fragment extends Fragment {
    MyAsyncTaskm2 mt;
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;
    private TextView textView4;
    private TextView textView5;
    private TextView textView6;
    private TextView textView7;
    private TextView textView8;

    private EditText editText1;
    private EditText editText2;
    private EditText editText3;
    private EditText editText4;
    private EditText editText5;
    private EditText editText6;
    private EditText editText7;
    private EditText editText8;

    public Mon2Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View Fr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mon2, container, false);

        textView1 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text1m);

        textView2 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text2m);

        textView3 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text3m);

        textView4 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text4m);

        textView5 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text5m);

        textView6 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text6m);

        textView7 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text7m);

        textView8 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.text8m);


        editText1 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext1m);

        editText2 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext2m);

        editText3 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext3m);

        editText4 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext4m);

        editText5 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext5m);

        editText6 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext6m);

        editText7 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext7m);

        editText8 = Fr.findViewById(R.id.edittext8m);

        String id = null;
        Activity act = getActivity();
        if (act instanceof Others2) {
            id = ((Others2) act).sendData();
        }
        mt = new MyAsyncTaskm2();
        mt.execute(id);


        TextEditorSet(editText1);
        TextEditorSet(editText2);
        TextEditorSet(editText3);
        TextEditorSet(editText4);
        TextEditorSet(editText5);
        TextEditorSet(editText6);
        TextEditorSet(editText7);
        TextEditorSet(editText8);

        Changer(editText1, textView1);
        Changer(editText2, textView2);
        Changer(editText3, textView3);
        Changer(editText4, textView4);
        Changer(editText5, textView5);
        Changer(editText6, textView6);
        Changer(editText7, textView7);
        Changer(editText8, textView8);


        return Fr;
    }

    private void Changer(final EditText ET, final TextView TV) {
        TV.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                TV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                ET.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                imm.showSoftInput(ET, 0);

                ET.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                            String value = ET.getText().toString();

                            TV.setText(value);

                            ET.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            TV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;

                    }

                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void TextEditorSet(EditText ET) {

        ET.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        ET.setSingleLine();

        ET.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ET.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    }


    public String[] Text_getter() {
        String[] myStr = new String[8];
        myStr[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
        myStr[1] = editText2.getText().toString();
        myStr[2] = editText3.getText().toString();
        myStr[3] = editText4.getText().toString();
        myStr[4] = editText5.getText().toString();
        myStr[5] = editText6.getText().toString();
        myStr[6] = editText7.getText().toString();
        myStr[7] = editText8.getText().toString();
        return myStr;
    }


    class MyAsyncTaskm2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            Database db = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
            String id = params[0];
            boolean test = false;
            if (db.classDao().doesGroupExist(id)) {
                test = true;
            }
            return test;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result)
                Set();
        }


        public void Set() {
            //String[] arr = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
            Activity act = getActivity();
            if (act instanceof Others2) {
                textView1.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[0]);

                textView2.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[1]);

                textView3.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[2]);

                textView4.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[3]);

                textView5.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[4]);

                textView6.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[5]);

                textView7.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[6]);

                textView8.setText(((Others2) act).sendDataM()[7]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Dao and ArrayConverter**

```
@androidx.room.Dao
public interface Dao {

    @Query("SELECT monday FROM  ClassEntity WHERE id_of_a_group = :id")
    String[] findFromMonday(String id);
}

public class ArrayConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public String[] fromClasses(String subjects){
        String[] array = subjects.split(",");
        return array;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String toClasses(String[] subjects){
        String result = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : subjects) {
                sb.append(s).append(",");
            }
            result = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).toString();

        return result;
    }

}
```

The compiler points on the `Set()` method. I tried different things but none of them worked.
 Tried debugging which ended unsuccessfully. Hoping you can help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you debug to print out the value of `String[] arrayRetrieven = sendDataM()` just before doing any textViewX.setText(..)?

public void Set() {
            Activity act = getActivity();
            if (act instanceof Others2) {
                  // Somewhere here print that value
            }
}

Comment: And I think it's just better to call sendDataM() once and assign its returned value to a variable and access that local variable instead of calling sendDataM() for each textView.setText...

Comment: The value is this "["sometext","sometext","sometext","sometext","sometext"]" @denis_lor

Comment: That means that when you are trying to set `textView6` text with the element of your array at position 5 there is an indexOutOfBoundsException, which means your array have only items till position 4 as you have 5 elements with `sometext` value. Starting from position 0 till position 4.

Comment: Now start to debug why you save only 5 values instead of saving 8 values as you expect when you retrieve your array and then try to set the text of 8 TextViews in your Set() method. Most probably you are trying to save those values in `b.putStringArray("array_for_m", db.classDao().findFromMonday(numberPickersValues));` so try to debug why `findFromMonday` gives you 5 elements instead of 8, if you are expected to always have 8 elements. Otherwise if there might not be that much elements you need to change some logic on how you set the text and what should be a default value if there is none.

Comment: @denis_lor I understand what you are saying but I assure there is nothing wrong with that. Apparently, you did not understand the problem. It has to give me an array but instead, it gives me a string like "['','','','',''....]".So when I call for the 1 element (not 0) it shows "indexOutOfBoundsException".

Comment: Can you confirm me what does `findFromMonday(..)` return as type? Or just show me the function definition so I can see what it returns?

Comment: Please post the whole function findFromMonday(..) which you call in order to get the String[] values that you want to later on show in the TextView-s in your Set() method. That will also help to check if you are doing any parsing before returning the right String[] which you are expecting

Comment: Most probably the data coming from findFromMonday(..) has not been formatted as you expected it. The work you are doing with the Bundle, so to set the data and retrieve it between activities is correct, there is nothing wrong. That means that whatever is coming from findFromMonday(..) is your expected array of strings within a string or within an array of strings with 1 value, and this value is exactly your array of strings. Please post findFromMonday(..) code in order to check the behaviour.

Comment: Okay, sorry for not doing it at the start. @denis_lor

Comment: @denis_lor posted)

Comment: let's go step by step, in this line `b.putStringArray("array_for_m", db.classDao().findFromMonday(numberPickersValues));` can you check what does `db.classDao().findFromMonday(numberPickersValues)` returns? Put it in a variable to debug it or debug it via the console. Maybe it's easier for you to do `String[] arrayForM = db.classDao().findFromMonday(numberPickersValues);` and then before doing `b.putStringArray("array_for_m", arrayForM);`, check what's the value of `arrayForM` variable.